# JavaScript works, but when website reload, sometimes javascript does not work in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

JavaScript works, but when website reload, sometimes javascript does not work. 
When javascript does not work, the `console.log` works, but the `querySelectorAll` does not work. I change the data I get from `querySelectorAll` to array. And when I do `console.log` it, the empty array is printed.

I don't know how to approach this problem....

Parts of manifest.json

```
"content_scripts": [
{
    "run_at": "document_idle",
    "matches": ["https://www.something.com/*"],// this url is example
    "css": ["extensionStyle.css"],
    "js": ["Controller.js"]
 }
],

"permissions": ["declarativeContent", "storage", "activeTab", "tabs"]
```

Parts of Controller.js

```
// All the codes in my JavaScript work on this code. 
// When I do console.log it, the empty NodeList is printed.

const articles = document.querySelectorAll(
"#container.article>.articles>article");
```

I didn't think this code was wrong, and I knew it would run always.

Comment: can you also share the HTML ? and how the HTML elements are loaded ? do you have some async method loading them ?

Comment: According to the https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts, I am not load HTML separately because "content_script" uses "matches" to connect JavaScript to URLs.

Comment: Try to set `run_at`'s value to `document_end`, that mean the script will execute only when the document is ready

Comment: Setting "run_at" to "document_end" will not work at all...ㅠ_ㅠ

Comment: What do you mean with `not work at all`? The script not even run or still run but nothing happen?

Comment: document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ 
    // your code goes here
}, false); You could add a listener to wait until your dom loaded to execute your code. The element will be available at that time

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with my code working in the console, but then not on refresh.  For me, the problem was that I was accessing a frame within the page.  But I accidentally noticed that in the Javascript Context (Can't find much info on this), if you run your code under the correct context everytime, you won't have this issue.  If that's the issue you're having, but very common when I was trying to execute my code from the console and from the extension.    [image: see image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute code when site is fully loaded

```
window.onload = function() {
  const articles = document.querySelectorAll(
  "#container.article>.articles>article");
};
```